# Effect of saturated beam laser on transmission in solid materials

Tags: optics, laser, experimental-technique, photonics

The transmission measurement setup commonly features a source (e.g. laser), steering mirrors, an integrating sphere, coupled to a power meter (or spectrometer). For a solid sample placed between the source and the integrating sphere (and power meter), the transmission is calculated using: $T = P_{out}/P_{in}$, whereby $P_{in}$ is the incident power and $P_{out}$ is the power of the laser beam transmitted through the material.

My question is this: If at a certain laser diode current $I_{LD}$, the beam becomes saturated as seen from a beam profiler, is it alright to use $P_{in}$ and $P_{out}$ as they are to calculate $T$? Or is it necessary to use filters in this case? How is the $T$ value affected by beam saturation?

I understand that filters should be used for saturated beams to protect the equipment (as in cameras, beam profilers or spectrometers). But I am not really sure how the saturation of the beam will affect the power measured by a power meter. My thinking is that since we are only measuring the relative flux with and without the sample placed between the integrating sphere/power meter, having filters in the setup does not really have any effect on the $T$ value obtained, and we should get approximately the same $T$ with or without the filters in place.

But is it right to do so?

Thank you very much. My understanding of optics is rather limited and any answer will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You mean that because the beam profiler’s detector has saturated might also the detector attached to the integrating sphere be saturation too? Well there is no accurate way to know that. You would need to plot the detector signal as a function of laser power and see if it is linear.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by a saturated beam? My understanding is that you are talking about saturated detectors, which has nothing to do with the actual laser light or its power measurement. Transmission measurements are typically done at low powers to avoid any nonlinearities. But first you should clarify what is meant by "saturated beam".

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have edited my question to include a photo to more properly show what I meant by saturated beam as seen from profiler/spectrometer (in this case, this is as seen from spectrometer).

@boyfarrell Yes, that is what I meant. If the beam appears to be saturated as seen from profiler/spectrometer, does this in any way affect the readings I get from a separate power detector which I use to measure $Pout$? When the plot of detector signal vs. laser power deviates from linear, what does this imply?

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thank you for your reply. I apologize for my rather vague phrasing. By saturated beam, I meant that the some of the pixels of the profiler look saturated at a certain laser power. I have included a photo of the spectrum as seen from the spectrometer in my question.

Comment: the power meter is independent of the spectrometer. If the spectrometer is saturated the powermeter can or cannot be saturated as well, depends on your scale. If the powermeter is set to measure up to 3W, then 10 W are well above saturation. If you can have an accurate reading of the power at the powermeter, then whatever the spectrometer/camera show you are irrelevant. But maybe you should think what you want to extrapolate from the camera and spectral data and also act accordingly. ie if that data is important, it should also not saturate.

Comment: Your explanation  @JoséAndrade has cleared my confusion. Thank you very much.